# Starting WebView fit to scale, with pinch zoom

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I am trying to load a url into a webview, its actually a screen share stream into a phone app.

I have a couple of issues I need help with.

1. WebView starts always zoomed at the top left corner [image]
2. There are zoom controls and fit to scale button, and after zooming you can move around by touch, however the two finger pinch zoom does not work.
3. Adding the `setWebViewClient` as below, enables pinch zoom but gives two more problems; there are additional -+ buttons, and zooming by pinch the original -+/fit to scale buttons become zoomed as well

[image]

[image]

```
            screenShareWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
            screenShareWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
            screenShareWebView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
            screenShareWebView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
            screenShareWebView.settings.displayZoomControls = true
            screenShareWebView.scrollBarStyle = WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
            screenShareWebView.isScrollbarFadingEnabled = true

            screenShareWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true //needs to be true or else it doesnt work

            screenShareWebView.loadUrl(it)
```

the pinch zoom is enabled (with the extra buttons) with

```
        screenShareWebView.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String?) {
        val javascript ="javascript:document.getElementsByName('viewport'[0].setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0');"

            view.loadUrl(javascript)
        }
    })
```

So i need to start fit to scale, enable pinch zoom if possible and dont add extra buttons

Comment: do you this in your html `<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=980" />` or any desired with ?

Comment: Sorry, I know webview and PHP, but very few on native side in android studio...